# Javascript Variable Sometimes Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question has been asked several times, but I couldn't seem to find a solution that worked for me in any of the previous questions. I have a variable that gets set when my HTML page is done loading, but sometimes when my code tries to access that variable, it says that it is undefined. I'm not sure why, since I believe I am waiting for everything to load properly. This exception seems to happen randomly, as most of the time all the code runs fine. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
var globalVar;

function initStuff(filePath) {
    // I wait till the HTML page is fully loaded before doing anything
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var video = document.getElementById("videoElementID");

        // My parseFile() function seems to run smoothly
        var arrayOfStuff = parseFile(filePath); 

        if (arrayOfStuff == null) {
            console.error("Unable to properly parse the file.");
        } else {
            setGlobalVariable(arrayOfStuff);
            video.addEventListener("play", updateVideoFrame, false);
        }
    });
}

function setGlobalVariable(arrayOfStuff) {
    window.globalVar = arrayOfStuff;
}

function updateVideoFrame() {
    // A bunch of other code happens first

    // This is the line that fails occasionally, saying 
    // "window.globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray[0] is undefined"
    var test = window.globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray[0].aProperty;
}
```

The only thing that I can think of that might be causing this problem is some sort of synchronicity issue. I don't see why that would be the case, though. Help please!

### Edit:

In case the asynchronicity issue is coming from my `parseFile(xmlFile)` method, here is what I'm doing there. I thought it couldn't possibly be causing the issue, since I force the method to happen synchronously, but in case I'm wrong, here it is:

```
function parseKML(xmlFile) {
    var arrayOfStuff = new Array();

    // Turn the AJAX asynchronicity off for the following GET command
    $.ajaxSetup( { async : false } );
    // Open the XML file
    $.get(xmlFile, {}, function(xml) {
        var doc = $("Document", xml);   
        // Code for parsing the XML file is here
        // arrayOfStuff() gets populated here
    });

    // Once I'm done processing the XML file, I turn asynchronicity back on, since that is AJAX's default state
    $.ajaxSetup( { async : true } );

    return arrayOfStuff;
}
```

Comment: is parseFile(filePath) an ajax request?

Comment: Seems like your external file has not been totally parsed (occasionally and likely) at the time `updateVideoFrame` function executes. If it's an Ajax call, you might wanna make it synchronous otherwise you can use a `complete` function in your Ajax function to call `updateVideoFrame`.

Comment: @Sebas - No, it is a bunch of JQuery calls to parse an XML file.

Comment: @inhan - So if I wanted to make it synchronous, should I do that at the beginning of my `initStuff()` method? I already make a `$.ajaxSetup( { async : false } );` call in my `parseFile(filePath)` function, but at the end of that function I was switching it back using `$.ajaxSetup( { async : true } );`.

Comment: Hard to tell what particular line of code is causing it. In these conditions I add `console.log`s here and there to see which function is running before which, to debug.

Comment: Also use try catch block to handle the errors... It may help you to find the problem

Comment: @Talha - Thanks for the suggestion of a try-catch block. I put the code in `updateVideoFrame()` in one and that solved my problem. Now it fails quietly and keeps trying to update the video frame until the file is parsed. I know that's not the ideal solution, though. I'd rather force it to wait until the file is done parsing before calling `updateVideoFrame()`, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do in your code is figure out which part of:

```
window.globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray[0]
```

is undefined.

Since you have multiple chained property references and array references, it could be many different places in the chain.  I'd suggest either set a breakpoint right before your reference it examine what's in it or use several `console.log()` statement sto output each nested piece of the structure in order to find out where your problem is.

```
console.log("globalVar = " + globalVar);
console.log("globalVar[0] = " + globalVar[0]);
console.log("globalVar[0].aProperty = " + globalVar[0].aProperty);
console.log("globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray = " + globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray);
console.log("globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray[0] = " + globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray[0]);
```

If the problem is that `globalVar` isn't yet set, then you have a timing problem or an initialization problem.

If the problem is that one of the other properties isn't set, then you aren't initializing globalVar with what you think you are.

You may also want to write your code more defensibly so it fails gracefully if some of your data isn't set properly.

Comment: `console.dir()` is great for dumping arrays and objects.

Comment: Judging by the error message in the comment, everything up to and including `anArray` is defined, but `anArray` has no `0` property.

Comment: Also use try catch block to handle the errors... It may help you to find the problem

Comment: @powerbuoy - Thanks for the console.dir() tip, that was helpful!

Comment: @GGG - Yes, but `anArray` is only undefined sometimes, seemingly randomly, which is why I am confused. When run on the same input, I would think the array should be defined every time, but it's not, which is why I'm having trouble tracking down what is going wrong, and why I think it has to do with synchronization.

Comment: @Steph "...anArray[0] is undefined" should indicate that `anArray` *is* defined, it just doesn't have a '0' property (probably an empty array).

Comment: @Steph - Your comments indicate that `ParseFile` uses an asynchronous ajax function.  You don't include the code for that, but my guess is that you aren't waiting until the ajax function completes before letting your code go on and use the results.  Thus it's a race to see whether your code tries to use the value before the ajax function actually fills it in.  Code that relies on the result of an asynchronous ajax function cannot run synchronously - it must run in the success handler for the ajax function or be called from the success handler.  Code has to be restructured to work this way.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I've edited my post to include the code for the `parseFile(xmlFile)` method so you can see what I'm talking about. I'm sure you are correct that I'm not letting the AJAX function complete, but I can't see how because I thought I was already explicitly forcing it to wait. Can you take a look and let me know what you think?

Comment: @Steph - OK, so it appears you're trying to use synchronous ajax.  It would be interesting to devise a test to see if it's always running as synchronous or not.  You could just put a `console.log("success handler")` in the ajax completion function and put `console.log("end of parseFile")` at the end of `parseFile()` and make sure they always come in the right order.  Beyond that, you need to inspect `arrayOfStuff` at the end of `parseFile()` and see if it always has in it what you expect.  This is basic debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use defensive programming. 
http://www.javascriptref.com/pdf/ch23_ed2.pdf

Example:

```
var video = document.getElementById("videoElementID") || 0;
```

-

```
if( video && video.addEventListener ){
    video.addEventListener("play", updateVideoFrame, false);
}
```

Here's another version of your code.

```
window.globalVar = globalVar || [];
function setGlobalVariable(arrayOfStuff) {
    window.globalVar = arrayOfStuff;
}
function updateVideoFrame() {
    // A bunch of other code happens first

    // This is the line that fails occasionally, saying
    // "window.globalVar[0].aProperty.anArray[0] is undefined"
    if( window.globalVar ){
        var g = window.globalVar || [];
        var d = (g[0] || {})["aProperty"];
        // etc...
    }else{
        console.error( "test error." );
    }

}
function initStuff(filePath) {
    // I wait till the HTML page is fully loaded before doing anything
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var video = $("#videoElementID");

        // My parseFile() function seems to run smoothly
        var arrayOfStuff = parseFile(filePath) || [];

        if (arrayOfStuff == null || video == null ) {
            console.error("Unable to properly parse the file.");
        } else {
            setGlobalVariable(arrayOfStuff);
            video.bind("play", updateVideoFrame);
        }
    });
}
```